# Hyper-V Replication failing sync

Tags: windows, backup, hyper-v, replication

I have enabled Hyper-V replication for our ERP VM between 2 Windows Server 2012 R2. Every 2 months the master server runs out of space because the replication sync fails. It creates many .AVHDX files up to the point that we run out of space and all VMs are paused.

It seems that the sync fails during the night, when both server have the backup process. The only error i have in the event log is a 19050.

Does the Hyper-V replication and Windows backup not work together? Anyone managed to make them work together?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like whoever made the system made an improvisation and did not take into account the space requirements. There are things needed to be considered except the actual occupied space by the ERP VM.

You need space for the following:

- ERP VM and its replica
- Snapshot space
- Replay space if you use LUNs
- Primary Backup space
- Additional backup space depending on the number of retained rollbacks

So you should extend space and re-schedule the backups in different day for each server.

Comment: The drive in question has 400 GB free space. That should be enough since the VM in question only has 80 GB. The problem is that Replication and Backup dont go well together. It wont sync while in backup state, and if enough time passes, the replication will get stuck and has to be re-enabled manually.

Comment: 80 GB of occupied space or the total VM disk size ?

Comment: 80GB is the total VM disk size. But the 15+ addional avhdx that amount to 400 GB. Now i disabled the replication and it combined so the total size is back to normal.